# Configure tomcat in AWS beanstalk with .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws, ebextensions

In AWS elastic beanstalk i want to deploy .war file, I'm using solution stack with Tomcat 9, to make my application work correctly i need to start this .war file with parameters(db password/user, db url etc.), how to configure Tomcat to start my artifact with these parameters by using `.ebextensions`?

Like this:

```java
java -Ddatasource.dialect=$DB_DIALECT \
           -Ddatasource.url=$DB_URL \
           -Ddatasource.username=$DB_USERNAME \
           -Ddatasource.password=$DB_PASSWORD \
           -jar applicatin.war
```

Comment: Is the DB deployed with the Elasticbeanstalk environment or outside of it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the commands feature but then you'd have to put the env vars for your db in there which wouldn't be as secure as it could be.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html
This example comes from the above link.

```
commands:
  python_install:
    command: myscript.py
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
    env:
      myvarname: myvarvalue
    test: "[ -x /usr/bin/python ]"
```

It might look like this for you;

```
commands:
  db_cmd:
    command: java -Ddatasource.dialect=$DB_DIALECT \
           -Ddatasource.url=$DB_URL \
           -Ddatasource.username=$DB_USERNAME \
           -Ddatasource.password=$DB_PASSWORD \
           -jar applicatin.war
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
    env:
      DB_DIALECT: myvarvalue
      DB_USERNAME: xxx
      DB_PASSWORD: xxx
```

I would put the commands into a script though and call it like this;

```
commands:
  db_cmd:
    command: ./db.sh
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
```

In the script I would add some calls to secrets manager to get the secrets you need. I only added one example of getting code from secrets manager but you'd need to get all three, of course.

```
#!/bin/bash
export DB_DIALECT=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id dbdialect --region us-east-1 | jq -r '.SecretString' | jq -r '.your_secret_key')
java -Ddatasource.dialect=$DB_DIALECT \
           -Ddatasource.url=$DB_URL \
           -Ddatasource.username=$DB_USERNAME \
           -Ddatasource.password=$DB_PASSWORD \
           -jar applicatin.war
```